# How to define name of wifi router instead of IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares

I am having a one scenario,

I have Wifi environment which is using to connect computer for internet sharing.

The Router is having USB port, i have connect the USB drive and share the data across to all computer.

Its sharing data perfectly through IP address. Means i have to pass the IP address to the share folder name like ("192.0.0.68/Docs").

My Question is: Can we define the name of this IP address so any one can easily use the name not a IP address?  This is a Router IP address,

Help will much appreciated.

Comment: Which platform is this? With Windows and others you can add entries in to your host file to map a name to an IP address.

Answer (score 6):

Add an entry to your `hosts` file (at `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS` on Windows) to tell your system the IP address of your router.  For example:

```
192.0.0.68   router
```

If you're on something other than Windows, Wikipedia has a table telling the [hosts file location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system) on all the usual suspect operating systems.  For example, on Mac OS X 10.2 and newer, the `hosts` file is at `/etc/hosts`, which is a symbolic link to `/private/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Nicole->I think, for implementing this way, first, we have to define the host name to router then we can use, and another point, Is there any other way can use this without host entry.

Comment: This creates the definition of that host name and this is how it's done.  Choose any name you like.  For example, in my own `hosts` file, I have entries for `comcastgateway`, `router`, `officejet` and `appletv`.  Your system resolves names by consulting its `hosts` files first.  If it doesn't find a matching entry there, it asks the DNS server.

Comment: How can we set this in MAC PC?

Comment: I've revised my answer for Mac OS X and other operating systems.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Nicole-> I agree your point. But this way, i have to add this entry in all PC those who wants to access the shared folder. Actually, I want to generate the common name so that any user can access shared folder by the name instead of IP address.

Comment: Yes, adding the same entry to every machine's `hosts` file is a pain.  Your alternative would be to run your own DNS server on your network.  But you'd need a pretty big network, e.g., a corporate intranet, to justify that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, but I don't think its require a DNS server. I tell you more about my approach. 
Actually, i am using a TPlink wifi router. By this router, we can share a usb drive data through the following stpes in the above link (http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?id=253) 
In last step 6 --> they are showing to access shared USD drive folder like //192.168.1.1/Volume1. But i don't want to access this through IP. 
I want to use name (like://router/volume1) instead of IP address(//192.168.1.1/Volume1).